vsftpd is not reachable from outside IP
I'm a server and I have ubuntu in my machine. I want to make a minecraft server and give access to myself and another person (an admin) a reachable FTP connection. I configured a lot, but I cannot reach my ftp server from outside network. I can reach it within my local network, but I cannot reach my directory from outside the local network. You can see the codes below. I also configure my router to forward the following ports: 25565, 21, 22. My goal is to reach my server outside from the local network as well as I reach it with local address.
vsftp.conf:
#
# The default compiled in settings are fairly paranoid. This sample file
# loosens things up a bit, to make the ftp daemon more usable.
# Please see vsftpd.conf.5 for all compiled in defaults.
#
# READ THIS: This example file is NOT an exhaustive list of vsftpd options.
# Please read the vsftpd.conf.5 manual page to get a full idea of vsftpd's
# capabilities.
#
#
# Run standalone?  vsftpd can run either from an inetd or as a standalone
# daemon started from an initscript.
listen=NO
#
# This directive enables listening on IPv6 sockets. By default, listening
# on the IPv6 "any" address (::) will accept connections from both IPv6
# and IPv4 clients. It is not necessary to listen on *both* IPv4 and IPv6
# sockets. If you want that (perhaps because you want to listen on specific
# addresses) then you must run two copies of vsftpd with two configuration
# files.
listen_ipv6=YES
#
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Disabled by default).
anonymous_enable=NO
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=YES
#
# Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
# if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
#local_umask=022
#
# Uncomment this to allow the anonymous FTP user to upload files. This only
# has an effect if the above global write enable is activated. Also, you will
# obviously need to create a directory writable by the FTP user.
#anon_upload_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this if you want the anonymous FTP user to be able to create
# new directories.
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
#
# Activate directory messages - messages given to remote users when they
# go into a certain directory.
dirmessage_enable=YES
#
# If enabled, vsftpd will display directory listings with the time
# in  your  local  time  zone.  The default is to display GMT. The
# times returned by the MDTM FTP command are also affected by this
# option.
use_localtime=YES
#
# Activate logging of uploads/downloads.
xferlog_enable=YES
#
# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES
#
# If you want, you can arrange for uploaded anonymous files to be owned by
# a different user. Note! Using "root" for uploaded files is not
# recommended!
#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever
#
# You may override where the log file goes if you like. The default is shown
# below.
#xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
#
# If you want, you can have your log file in standard ftpd xferlog format.
# Note that the default log file location is /var/log/xferlog in this case.
#xferlog_std_format=YES
#
# You may change the default value for timing out an idle session.
#idle_session_timeout=600
#
# You may change the default value for timing out a data connection.
#data_connection_timeout=120
#
# It is recommended that you define on your system a unique user which the
# ftp server can use as a totally isolated and unprivileged user.
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#
# Enable this and the server will recognise asynchronous ABOR requests. Not
# recommended for security (the code is non-trivial). Not enabling it,
# however, may confuse older FTP clients.
#async_abor_enable=YES
#
# By default the server will pretend to allow ASCII mode but in fact ignore
# the request. Turn on the below options to have the server actually do ASCII
# mangling on files when in ASCII mode.
# Beware that on some FTP servers, ASCII support allows a denial of service
# attack (DoS) via the command "SIZE /big/file" in ASCII mode. vsftpd
# predicted this attack and has always been safe, reporting the size of the
# raw file.
# ASCII mangling is a horrible feature of the protocol.
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
#
# You may fully customise the login banner string:
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
#
# You may specify a file of disallowed anonymous e-mail addresses. Apparently
# useful for combatting certain DoS attacks.
#deny_email_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd.banned_emails
#
# You may restrict local users to their home directories.  See the FAQ for
# the possible risks in this before using chroot_local_user or
# chroot_list_enable below.
chroot_local_user=YES
#
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
# (Warning! chroot'ing can be very dangerous. If using chroot, make sure that
# the user does not have write access to the top level directory within the
# chroot)
#chroot_local_user=YES
#chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
#
# You may activate the "-R" option to the builtin ls. This is disabled by
# default to avoid remote users being able to cause excessive I/O on large
# sites. However, some broken FTP clients such as "ncftp" and "mirror" assume
# the presence of the "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it.
#ls_recurse_enable=YES
#
# Customization
#
# Some of vsftpd's settings don't fit the filesystem layout by
# default.
#
# This option should be the name of a directory which is empty.  Also, the
# directory should not be writable by the ftp user. This directory is used
# as a secure chroot() jail at times vsftpd does not require filesystem
# access.
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
#
# This string is the name of the PAM service vsftpd will use.
pam_service_name=vsftpd
#
# This option specifies the location of the RSA certificate to use for SSL
# encrypted connections.
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=YES

#
# Uncomment this to indicate that vsftpd use a utf8 filesystem.
#utf8_filesystem=YES


user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/$USER/ftp
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_deny=NO
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES

pasv_enable=YES
port_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
# Passive Mode for VSFTP communication with server
pasv_min_port=10000
pasv_max_port=11000
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
listen_port=21
pasv_address=<My public IP>
pasv_addr_resolve=YES

Total Commander FTP log:
----------
Using sChannel (Secur32.dll) for SSL/TLS connection.
Connect to: (2024.05.29 20:50:13)
hostname=<My public IP>
username=admin
startdir=
<My public IP>=<My public IP again>
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.5)
AUTH TLS
234 Proceed with negotiation.
Client handshake...
Method: TLSv1.2
Cert subject: C=HU, S=Some-State, O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, E=telekbotond.58@gmail.com
Cert issuer: C=HU, S=Some-State, O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, E=telekbotond.58@gmail.com
USER admin
331 Please specify the password.
PASS ***********
230 Login successful.
SYST
215 UNIX Type: L8
FEAT
211-Features:
 EPRT
 EPSV
 MDTM
 PASV
 PBSZ
 PROT
 REST STREAM
 SIZE
 TVFS
211 End
HELP SITE
214-The following commands are recognized.
 ABOR ACCT ALLO APPE CDUP CWD  DELE EPRT EPSV FEAT HELP LIST MDTM MKD
 MODE NLST NOOP OPTS PASS PASV PORT PWD  QUIT REIN REST RETR RMD  RNFR
 RNTO SITE SIZE SMNT STAT STOR STOU STRU SYST TYPE USER XCUP XCWD XMKD
 XPWD XRMD
214 Help OK.
PBSZ 0
200 PBSZ set to 0.
PROT P
200 PROT now Private.
OPTS UTF8 ON
200 Always in UTF8 mode.
Connect ok!
PWD
257 "/" is the current directory
Almappa
TYPE A
200 Switching to ASCII mode.
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,42,101).
Server reports local IP -> Redirect to: <My public IP>
PORT 192,168,0,222,237,217
500 Illegal PORT command.

I also did a lot of research but don't find any answer for my problem.

Do not use FTP in 2024. Use sftp. FTP is outdated, plain and simple. The only sane reason for deploying FTP today is supporting software written thirty-forty years ago. Why is it outdated? Well, you've discovered one of the reasons; it requires multiple connections and states.

PORT command is an active mode command, which is not expected after PASV, which enters a passive mode. Either client is buggy, misconfigured or test suite is wrong.

@vidarlo there is one particular feature of FTP, a direct server-to-server transfer, which no one else has. And it doesn't need any special support from servers. You start one connection in passive mode, it provides connection data (IP and port), then you pass this data to other server in active mode, and voila, active server would connect directly to passive, data won't flow through the client. So I can imagine cases when FTP could actually be the preferred solution even in 2024. However, admittedly, this question is not one of such cases.

@NikitaKipriyanov I agree - I was too rash; there's cases, but in those cases the person configuring it is usually aware of why...

The error 500 Illegal PORT command often indicates that the client is trying to use the PORT command (active mode), which is not allowed by the server configuration or the network setup. Make sure your FTP client is set to use passive mode.
Your router shall forward ports 21 and 10000-11000 to your FTP server's internal IP address. This way, connections to your public IP on these ports are directed to your server. Make sure it is a static IP, you can set that in the router using the MAC address of the network interface you're using for this.
userlist_deny=NO
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=10000
pasv_max_port=11000
pasv_address=<Your Public IP> 
pasv_addr_resolve=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES

When you connect, the server should respond with something like:
227 Entering Passive Mode (203,0,113,5,39,150)
The response 227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,42,101) indicates that the FTP server is providing an incorrect IP address (0.0.0.0) for passive mode, which means the client cannot connect properly.
Restart the service and connect again. That should do it!
This is the root of the issue, as 0.0.0.0 is not a valid address for external clients to connect to.
Also, make sure it is configured to use passive mode.
If this solves the issue, a +1 would be nice! :-)

Linux firewall has helpers (both for filter and for NAT) that allow to not forward the set of ports and not permit them statically up front, but will do it dynamically, by parsing control connection and extracting the needed data from it (and altering it sometimes). Also, the 0.0.0.0 address in this case is just placeholder (we have to have the address here, but the server is behind NAT and doesn't know its own public IP); the client or NAT helper could (and should) put the real public IP address of the server there.

@NikitaKipriyanov The FTP helpers won't work if you use FTPS, like here, as it relies on iptables snooping the data from packets.

That's entirely true. I've missed the FTPS part.

I tried to forward the ports on my router: 25565, 20, 21, 22, 10000, 10001, 10002. And I also added these ports to my ufw. I'm also unable to reach my directory from outside, but the interesting part, that I saw this in my log when I try to connect with my local IP:
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,42,49).
Server reports local IP -> Redirect to: 192.168.1.100
Connected to PASV port
LIST
150 Here comes the directory listing.
Download
Waiting for server...
226 Directory send OK.```
